# Java mySql WHERE AND WHERE error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Help me please what is the bug in this code?

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM work_book WHERE mikor >= " + startTime + "AND mikor <= " + endTime;
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

And error message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mikor <=
>   1518303600000' at line 1

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Never use string concatenation to build SQL statements. Why, and what to do instead: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: **Voting to close as typo** You're missing a space after the start time and `AND`.

Comment: If you learn to use parameters you won't have this problem.

Comment: Thanks! That was the fault.

Answer (score 2):

I consider your problem as a typo, it is caused because you miss a space between `startTime` and `AND` operator :

```
" + startTime + "AND mikor <= "
//---------------^
```

**But the important things :**

`Date` should be between two quotes `'startTime'`, beside your code can be a victim of syntax error or SQL Injection, so instead use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM work_book WHERE mikor >= ? AND mikor <= ?";
try (PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);) {
    pst.setDate(1, startTime);
    pst.setDate(2, endTime);
    ...
}
```

Comment: If there were a quoting issue with `startTime`, the error would be earlier. The absense of the space before `AND` is the problem (well, the one asked about). It's just a typo.

Comment: Thank you, This is true @T.J.Crowder I mention this in my answer